# Writing 1.5 million rows in a file

Tags: python, python-3.x, strings, random

I am generating SQL statements (of MySQL format) and writing into a file to create 10,000 tables. Each table contains 5 columns with 1.5 million rows of data in each column. I generated these data by using regex and faker module. So, I have a loop of 10,000 (one for each **create table** statement) and within this loop, I have another loop of 1.5 million (to **insert** rows of data into each table created).

The code is running properly but is **extremely slow**. Is there any way to make this run considerably faster?

```
import rstr
import random
from faker import Faker
import time

fake = Faker()

name = ['Name', 'Person_Name', 'Customer_Name', 'Employee_Name', 'Contact_Name', 'CustName', 'EmpName']
ssn = ['SSN', 'Social_Security_Number', 'National_Identification_Number', 'NID', 'US_SSN', 'Social_Number', 'Social_Security_No', 'Social_Security_Num', 'Customer_Social_Security Number', 'Employee_Social_Security_Number']
address = ['Address', 'Customer_Location_Details', 'Employee_Address_Details', 'Address_Det.', 'Add_Line_1', 'Add_Line_2', 'Address_Line_1', 'Address_Line_2']
dob = ['DOB', 'Date_Of_Birth', 'Birth_Date', 'V_VLD_BRTH_DT', 'DAY_OF_BRTH', 'DT_OF_BIRTH']
phone = ['Phone_Number', 'Contact_Number', 'Office_Phone', 'Residential_phone', 'Contact_Phone']

ssn1='(?!000|.+0{4})(?:\d{9})'
ssn2='(?!000|.+0{4})(\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4})'
sList=[ssn1,ssn2]

db1='^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[/](0[1-9]|1[012])[/](19)\d\d$'
db2='^(19)\d\d$[.](0[1-9]|1[012])[.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])'
db3='^(19)\d\d$[-](0[1-9]|1[012])[-](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])'            
db4='^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[-](0[1-9]|1[012])[-](19)\d\d$'
db5='^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[.](0[1-9]|1[012])[.]\d\d$'
dbList=[db1,db2, db3, db4, db5]

p1='1[2-9][0-8][0-9][2-9][0-9]{2}[0-9]{4}'
p2='[2-9][0-8][0-9][2-9][0-9]{2}[0-9]{4}'
p3='001[2-9][0-8][0-9][2-9][0-9]{2}[0-9]{4}'
p4='[(][\d]{3}[)][ ]?[\d]{3}-[\d]{4}'
p5='\+1[2-9][0-8][0-9][2-9][0-9]{2}[0-9]{4}'
p6='(\d{3}\d{3}\d{4})'
p7='[2-9][0-8][0-9][-][2-9][0-9]{2}[-][0-9]{4}'
pList=[p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7]

tables=10001
rows=1500001

with open("D:\Output.sql", "a") as text_file:
    count = 0

    for i in range(1,tables):
        a=[]
        b=[]
        j=str(i)
        x=f'Tab_{i}'

        #a.append(random.choice(name)+'_'+j)
        #a.append(random.choice(ssn)+'_'+j)
        #a.append(random.choice(address)+'_'+j)
        #a.append(random.choice(dob)+'_'+j)
        #a.append(random.choice(phone)+'_'+j)
        a.extend(f'{random.choice(n)}_{j}' for n in (name, ssn, address, dob, phone))

        text_file.write(f"create table Python_test.{x}({a[0]} VARCHAR(255),{a[1]} VARCHAR(255),{a[2]} VARCHAR(255),{a[3]} VARCHAR(255),{a[4]} VARCHAR(255));\n")

        start = time.time()
        for j in range(1,rows):
            text_file.write(f"insert into {x}({a[0]},{a[1]},{a[2]},{a[3]},{a[4]}) values ('{fake.name()}','{rstr.xeger(random.choice(sList))}','{fake.address()}','{rstr.xeger(random.choice(dbList))}','{rstr.xeger(random.choice(pList))}');\n")

        print(time.time() - start) 
        text_file.write('\n')
        count+=1
        print(count)
```

Comment: What are `name` `ssn` `address` `dob` `phone` and where are they defined?

Comment: What's the purpose of this exercise? Is it homework? Surely creating 10,000 SQL tables isn't something we'd want to do in real life. What are your concerns - speed? Python style? SQL style?

Comment: @AJNeufeld Sorry for the inconvenience. I have attached the full code. The code is working. But it is taking a huge amount of time.

Comment: Please define "extremely slow", since that is subjective. It's probably very fast compared to some measures. A rough estimate of the system used and the current execution time would be good.

Comment: It might be faster to create a list, NumPy array or Pandas DataFrame with all the random entries, and only then loop over the contents, so you don't have to call the random functions inside each loop (it'll depend a bit on the memory available).

Comment: There is a fair chance it's largely the random generation of numbers, names and addresses that is causing the slowdown. Do you really want to measure (and improve) the generation of random entries? Or do you want to improve the output writing?

Comment: Lets assume 500 bytes per line.  500 bytes/line*15 000 000 lines/table*10 000 tables/file =  75 000 000 000 000 bytes/file. Writing 75 TB takes time and it would surprise me a lot if your program spends a noticable amount of time on anything other than writing to disc.

Comment: Also, have you talked to your db administrator about your plan of dumping 15 billion insert statemens into the system in one go?

Comment: Just to add to @Taemyr's comment: the very fastest SSDs today have write speeds of ~3.4GB/s. You would need a parallel RAID-0 of *12* of the fastest SSDs of the planet, just bring the pure time for even *writing the output file* to 30 minutes. This is assuming that *no other* I/O takes place during that time, that the 75 TB file largely fits in cache and that the writes are fully sequential and evenly distributed across the drives.

Comment: @00 I want to reduce the overall time. Be it an improvement on generation of random entries or improvement on output writing. As of now, creation of each table takes around 25 mins each (Each iteration). I need 10,000 tables (10,000 iterations).

Comment: Profile it to find the bottleneck. Easy start: removing *all* random calls, and just write the same line (of roughly the proper length) to file, so you have 1500001 identical lines in each file. If the execution drops by 50% or more, the random calls are a notable culprit. If the execution hardly varies, the disk I/O is very likely your bottleneck.

Comment: To add to JörgWMittag and Taemyr's comments: do you know the type of disk you are using; any specifications that you know about it?

Comment: @00 It's an hdd. Also, i will try your method to find the bottleneck.

Comment: HDD does not mean too much without an RPM, but assuming this means a spinning drive, that likely means it will already be slower than an SSD; see also the comments above. Good luck with profiling, and let us know what you find.

Comment: @00 I removed the random calls in the inner loop and wrote a string (of approx same length) 1.5 million times in the file. It took 4 secs (with the random and faker calls it took 21.5mins).
In another instance, i removed **just** the random calls and kept everything else as it is ( including the regex function and faker). It took 22.5 minutes to run. 
So it seems the regex and faker function calls are the bottleneck.

Comment: Ok, that was easy. So, now the question you should be asking yourself: do you *really* need (completely) random entries? Can you do, whatever you are testing, with identical lines? Or can you create a set of, say, 100 different lines, and simply loop through those continuously while writing 1500001 rows?

Comment: Or perhaps you mimick the random data by looping through *parts* of the entries, each a list of different lengths. So you could have 5 first names, 7 last names, 13 dobs, 17 street names, 19 street numbers etc, and then simply loop over them (the prime numbers ensures there'll be few identical lines). `itertools.cycle` could be handy.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98203/discussion-between-subhadeep-majumder-and-0-0).

Answer (score 11):

### Use `open` in a `with`

...so that you can be guaranteed of file closure regardless of any potential exceptions.

### Use f-strings

So that something like this:

```
x='Tab_'+str(i)
```

turns into

```
x = f'Tab_{i}'
```

### Computers are good at repetition

```
a.append(random.choice(name)+'_'+str(i))
a.append(random.choice(ssn)+'_'+str(i))
a.append(random.choice(address)+'_'+str(i))
a.append(random.choice(dob)+'_'+str(i))
a.append(random.choice(phone)+'_'+str(i))
```

can be

```
a.extend(f'{random.choice(n)}_{i}' for n in (name, ssn, address, dob, phone))
```

### Injection attacks

Unless you're *really* confident about the source, safety and validity of your data, constructing a string and sending it off as executable SQL is enemy number one of database security. This is what prepared statements are for. It's unclear what flavour of SQL you need, so it's unclear which library you'll need for this.

### Combined assignment/increment

```
count=count+1
```

can be

```
count += 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I am trying to generate **create** and **insert into** sql statements (for mysql db) through python. It seems Python does not support prepared statements. Any library suggestions for this?

Comment: Python definitely does support prepared statements, but you have to use a library - maybe https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/

Answer (score 6):

## Docstrings

You should include a [`docstring`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#documentation-strings) at the beginning of every module, class, and function you write. This will allow documentation to identify what your code is supposed to do.

## `with open` vs `file = open`

Currently, you open the file with `text_file = open("D:\Output.sql", "a", encoding="utf-8")`, and manually close it with `text_file.close()`. You can save yourself from having to do this with opening the file using `with open(...) as ...:`. This lets you work with the file, and once done and out of scope, can continue writing the program. *"But wait. What about closing the file?"*. When you use `with`, once you are out of the scope of the `with`, it closes itself automatically.

## Magic Numbers

```
for i in range(1,10001): ...
for j in range(1,1500001): ...
```

At first look, I had no idea what these numbers were supposed to represent. You should assign these numbers to variables, and use those variables instead. This makes the code cleaner and easier to maintain. What if you wanted to change the number of tables or number of people? You'd need to find every instance of that magic number (should you use it more than once) and change it. Having it assigned to a variables fixes this problem, as you can just change the value of the variable.

## String Formatting `f""`

`text_file.write('create table Python_test.'+x+'('+a[0]+' VARCHAR(255),'+a[1]+' VARCHAR(255),'+a[2]+' VARCHAR(255),'+a[3]+' VARCHAR(255),'+a[4]+' VARCHAR(255));\n')`

This hurts to read. All the `+` split apart the string and makes it really hard to know what the whole string is. My solution is to use `f"..."`. This allows you to directly incorporate variables into your strings, without having to `+...+`, and also avoiding (if present) `+str(...)+` which is *very* ugly to me.

## Objects

Having a redefined list with fixed positions of properties of people is messy. Instead, you can generate a list with instances of a `Person`, and you can access their properties when incorporating it in your `SQL` string.

## `_` for unused loop variables

When you don't use a variable in a loop, like:

```
for i in range(5):
    print("Hi!")
```

You should use a `_`. This makes it clear that the variable used for the loop is not needed, and should be ignored.

## Helper Functions

I wrote a few helper functions for generating some random values in your code. Using helper functions in your code can really help you, as you don't have to cram everything into one function.

*Exclaimer: I had no idea what you were trying to do when inserting data into your tables, so I left that blank. It also didn't help that `fake` and `rstr` weren't defined / weren't shown in your program.*

***Updated Code***

```
"""
Module Docstring
A description of your program goes here
"""

import random

class Person():
    """
    Class to store properties of Person
    """

    def __init__(self, name, ssn, address, dob, phone):
        self.name = name
        self.ssn = ssn
        self.address = address
        self.dob = dob
        self.phone = phone

def generate_ssn():
    """
    Returns a randomly generated SSN
    """
    return f"{random.randint(100, 999)}-{random.randint(10, 99)}-{random.randint(1000, 9999)}"

def generate_dob():
    """
    Returns a randomly generated address in format MM/DD/YYYY
    """
    return f"{random.randint(1, 12)}/{random.randint(1, 31)}/{random.randint(1919, 2019)}"

def generate_phone():
    """
    Returns a randomly generated phone number
    """
    return f"{random.randint(100, 999)}-{random.randint(100, 999)}-{random.randint(1000, 9999)}"

def generate_sql_script(num_people, num_tables, output_file):
    """
    Generates an SQL script for inserting people into tables
    """
    with open(output_file, "a") as out_file:
        people = []
        count = 0
        for i in range(1, num_people):
            people.append(Person(f"John_{i}",
                                 generate_ssn(),
                                 f"123 Main St_{i}",
                                 generate_dob(),
                                 generate_phone())
                         )
            random_person = random.choice(people)
            table = f"Tab_{i}"
            out_file.write(f'CREATE TABLE Python_test.{table}({random_person.name} VARCHAR(255), {random_person.ssn} VARCHAR(255), {random_person.address} VARCHAR(255), {random_person.dob} VARCHAR(255), {random_person.phone} VARCHAR(255)')

            for _ in range(1, num_tables):
                #Couldn't understand what this is doing with `fake` and `rstr`
                pass

            out_file.write('\n')
            count += 1
            print(count)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I have attached the full code in case you wanted to take a look into it.

Comment: you can split the string along mutliple lines ([string literal concatenation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literal-concatenation)) to reduce the line length and make the long strings better readable